# How to remove CDATA from chrome browsers live inject when live serving from VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I keep getting this script in live chrome browser from VSCode. How do I stop it from appearing?

```
// <![CDATA[ <-- For SVG support if ('WebSocket' in window) { (function () { function refreshCSS() { var sheets = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("link")); var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; ++i) { var elem = sheets[i]; var parent = elem.parentElement || head; parent.removeChild(elem); var rel = elem.rel; if (elem.href && typeof rel != "string" || rel.length == 0 || rel.toLowerCase() == "stylesheet") { var url = elem.href.replace(/(&|\?)_cacheOverride=\d+/, ''); elem.href = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + '_cacheOverride=' + (new Date().valueOf()); } parent.appendChild(elem); } } var protocol = window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'ws://' : 'wss://'; var address = protocol + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/ws'; var socket = new WebSocket(address); socket.onmessage = function (msg) { if (msg.data == 'reload') window.location.reload(); else if (msg.data == 'refreshcss') refreshCSS(); }; if (sessionStorage && !sessionStorage.getItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer')) { console.log('Live reload enabled.'); sessionStorage.setItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer', true); } })(); } else { console.error('Upgrade your browser. This Browser is NOT supported WebSocket for Live-Reloading.'); } // ]]>
```